# WorldWind Application in Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, gwt, worldwind

I was wondering if anyone has ported NASA's World Wind over to GWT. I would really like to see a couple of examples of setting up and using a world wind map in a GWT project and performing actions like creating geometries for the map and adding custom icons to the map. If anyone has any information on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

MPH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe anybody has ported NWW-J to GWT.  It would be a huge job, probably resulting in a huge web-app.

IMHO you should really be looking at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) It doesn't provide a 3d view, but it really is the standard for 2d browser-based mapping.

Alternatively, if your users have up-to-date browsers you could try [WebGlEarth](http://www.webglearth.org/).  It isn't as mature as OpenLayers, but it is 3d on an HTML5 browser.

Ian

Comment: Ian, Thanks for the reply. Do you know if OpenLayers can be stand alone i.e. have a static instance running on a page? I plan on setting up a widget in GWT that calls a map like Google Earth or OpenLayers but I would like for it to be able to be viewed if I have no internet connection. I know that the GE widget I am currently using cannot do this but was wondering if there was a GWT version available through WorldWind, OpenLayers, or WebGLEarth that could. 
Thanks again, MPH

Comment: Hi there.  OpenLayers is certainly capable of being run client-side, without an internet connection.  You still need to get your backdrop data however. It is technically possible to load Blue Marble (or similar) backdrop data from a local file-based URL - without an internet connection.  There is a GWT-wrapped OpenLayers library, though I haven't tried it.  I'm also working on an offline web-based mapping app. EMail me if you wish to discuss further details: ian@planetmayo.com